# Video in Beamer with multimedia package not playing

Tags: beamer, animations, presentations, animate, multimedia

I am trying to use the multimedia package in Beamer to play a local, non-embeded, video. The file compiles without errors; however, when I click on the place-holder image, it simply moves to the next slide. The MWE can be seen below, and the files can (tex, image, and video) can be downloaded here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/29upcupxzlnoc8v/beamervideo.tex
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h2b0jce86xhm4yg/sintel.avi
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5fl0q2b78yeg5s1/sintel.jpg
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0phqobyb8nwrusn/sintel.mp4

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\title{Video in Beamer presentation}
\begin{document}
\frame{\maketitle}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\textit{Sintel} trailer 480p MP4}
        \begin{center}
        \movie[width=\textwidth,showcontrols=true]
        {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{sintel.jpg}}{sintel.avi} \\
        Click on picture to play the movie
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Does this work for anyone? I am not sure if maybe my PDF viewer (evince, Ubuntu) is not compatible, or if I am just using the multimedia package incorrectly? I found the example online and assumed it worked for the author.

While other packages can embed movies/animations easily, they often require the use of Adobe Acrobat and result in very large PDFs. My motivation for using the multimedia package is to **avoid using Adobe Acrobat**.

Edit: I included mp4 and avi versions of the video and tried both, but no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to use Okular, and not Evince. With Okular, the example you provided works as it should.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using LuaTeX to generate the PDf, Version beta-0.79.1 (TeX Live 2014) (rev 4971)  and `\usepackage{multimedia}` with `beamer`. And with this version it's is possible to embedded `*.avi` and `*.mp4` formats (I tested) in conjunction to the latest PDF viewer OKULAR. Possibly the error is related with the codec behind the video. This are the codec properties that works:

MP4 Codec: H.264

AVI Codec: ITU H.264