# Okular to play embedded videos in Beamer

Tags: beamer, movie15, okular, multimedia

I have been trying to play embedded videos in presentations created in `pdflatex/Beamer` in Okular. I have read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1574) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158771) but to no avail!

Any suggestions?

The version of **Okular** being used *is 0.13.3 using KDE devlopment platform 4.7.4*. I am running **Ubuntu 11.10**.

**My minimum working example is**

```
\documentclass[bookmarks=true]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\setbeamercolor{structure}{bg=yellow, fg=black}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
% or whatever

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% or whatever

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}

%  \usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{olivegreen}{rgb}{85, 107, 47}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide Title Here}
% 
% \centering
% \includemovie{6.5cm}{6.5cm}{waves.avi}
\movie{6cm}{6cm}{waves.wmv}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**My video file is uploaded here for you to download and use.**

[AVI file](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13223318/waves.avi) and [wmv file](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13223318/waves.wmv)

**All I see in Okular is this:**

[image]

`:(`

Comment: Video inclusion is not well supported by viewers: the usual position is that if you want a multimedia PDF you've got to use Adobe Reader.

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, but it would seem that I need a full version of acrobat reader. All I have is acroread 9.5.4 and that too the free version.

Comment: @JosephWright: Okular is actually one of the few viewers that support video inclusion. For example, my answer works with Okular, but fails with evince, qpdfview and acroread on Arch Linux.

Comment: NOTE that `olivegreen` color will result in white, I think. [hyperref - XColor - Specifying Color in RGB or CYMK does not work correctly - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586350/xcolor-specifying-color-in-rgb-or-cymk-does-not-work-correctly)

Answer (score 18):

I managed to get your example working by using:

```
\movie[
  height = 6cm,
  width = 6cm,
  showcontrols,
  poster
] 
{}{waves.wmv}
```

[image: Okular success]

Note that I did that on Arch Linux with:

```
$ okular --version
Qt: 4.8.5
KDE Development Platform: 4.12.3
Okular: 0.18.3
```

For more details on the `multimedia` package, check [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1576/15560) or the [official documentation](http://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! Will try this soon and mark an answer (your answer)

Comment: Hi, I've been trying this solution with okular 1.5.3 and TeX Live 2018 and it does not work. After 4 years, do we finally have a working solution to this problem?? I am on Arch and I have phonon-qt5-vlc installed.

Comment: It works (in okular, evince, pympress etc). The only catch was the movie was invisible at first, and you need to click on it to start.

Comment: I had a .flv video embedded using media9. First I thought it was not working, but then I noticed that I had to enter the presentation mode of Okular for it to be played.

Answer (score 5):

To complement [BenC’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168715/28608) from the displaying side:

I found it necessary (at least on Ubuntu 14.04) to change the backend of Phonon (which is used by Okular to play videos) to the VLC one. For me it sufficed to install the respective package (`phonon-backend-vlc` on Debian-based Linuxes).