# How read movie with LaTex?

Tags: beamer, sharelatex, multimedia

I make a presentation with LaTex using `beamer`.

I have succeeded in add movie in Sharelatex and my code is as follows :

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{center}
        \movie[width=0.5\textwidth,showcontrols=true]
        {% placeholder = text or image
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{myPic.png}
        }%
        {myMovie.avi} % video filename
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But I can't read my movie in Ubuntu. I read in some site it's because my PDF reader can't. I may understand it's possible but I doesn't find how.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Which pdf reader are you using?

Comment: My pdf reader is Evince.

Comment: If you can french: [Intégrer des vidéos dans des fichiers PDF](http://linuxfr.org/news/integrer-des-videos-dans-des-fichiers-pdf#lire-un-pdf-avec-vid%C3%A9os-int%C3%A9gr%C3%A9es)

Comment: My bad: I edited your original post deleting the fact that your OS is Ubuntu. I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned you are using Ubuntu, the question [PDF viewer combined with video player](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629672/pdf-viewer-combined-with-video-player) on Askubuntu suggest to [use Okular to read the video embedded in your PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163089/okular-to-play-embedded-videos-in-beamer).

Indeed, all pdf-reader do not support [movies-, screen- or rich media-annotations](http://linuxfr.org/news/integrer-des-videos-dans-des-fichiers-pdf#le-format-pdf-et-les-vid%C3%A9os); `evince` is one of them.

Following MWE worked for me with `.avi` and `.mp4` videos, when open with `Okular: 0.19.3`.

```
\documentclass[bookmarks=true]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Go Ahead, Make My Day}
        \begin{center}
            \movie[%
                height = 6cm,%
                width = 6cm,%
                showcontrols,%
                poster%
            ]%
            {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}}
            {SampleVideo}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that:

- You must explicitly give your video file extension in your `tex` code (e.g. `SampleVideo`**`.avi`**, or `SampleVideo`**`.mp4`**);
- The video file must be located in the same folder than your `pdf`.
- You must have H.264 codecs installed on the computer.

Comment: I install Okular. The movie look like to play but nothing is read. May be an other problem with my code or my movie. Thanks for your help

Comment: It was the case for me indeed. But suggested MWE in the edit of my answer works fine for me. (`Okular: 0.19.3`)

Comment: I have `Okular: 0.19.3` too. I read if we don't add `\usepackage{media9}`, the movie is not really add to the PDF. And when I add `poster`, I can't play the movie.. I don't understant how your movie can play. But I test your code with an other movie, I add the package media9 and it's works. The only difference between my two movies are the extention.

Comment: I recompile and test it again... it works. But I found that `SampleVideo2.avi` should be in the same folder than your PDF. Moreover, you must explicitly give the movie file extension in your `.tex` document (e.g. `SampleVideo2.avi` and not `SampleVideo2`). It also worked for me with `.mp4` file.

Comment: It's works ! :D
The problem was I havn't H.264 codecs installed on my computer... Thanks a lot for your help ebo :)

Answer (score 3):

I added it as a hyperlink:

```
\href{movie.avi}{\includegraphics{movie.jpg}}
```

It's not embedded in the `.pdf`, but works with `*.avi` in the same folder as `.pdf`. Works with or without Acrobat Reader.